# Сборка WPF проекта с помощью Nant

Tags: c#, wpf, nant

Подскажите, какой состав ресурсов должен быть? Файлы xaml как должны быть добавлены?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Нужен [NantContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/)
2. Нужна [MSBuild Task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc4/help/tasks/msbuild.html)

Когда проект собирается с помощью [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wea2sca5(v=vs.90).aspx) никаких особенностей по составу проекта по сравнению со сборкой в Visual Studio нет.

Comment: Мне ответил сам ХэшКод:) 
Спасибо за направление в решении.